# Get only stderr output from subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, stderr

I want to run an external process in python, and process its `stderr` only.

I know I can use `subprocess.check_output`, but how can I redirect the stdout to `/dev/null` (or ignore it in any other way), and receive only the `stderr`?

Comment: the duplicate was wrong, `check_output` does not allow overriding `stdout`!

Comment: Is there a reason you need this for Python 2.7 only?

Comment: so do you want to catch the output in the case of an *error* or *success* or both?

Comment: @JRichardSnape: I need it for Python 2.7 only because my code base is on python 2.7.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala In case of both error and success I want to catch only stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple trick:

```
import subprocess
stderr_str = subprocess.check_output('command 2>&1 >/dev/null')
```

This will filter out the stdout, and keeps only the stderr.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you have tagged this [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), as in python 3.5 and up this would be simple using [`run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.run(..., stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stderr
```

With `check_output()` stdout simply cannot be redirected:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(('ls', 'asdfqwer'), stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.
```

Use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) objects and [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with python versions less than 3.5. Open `/dev/null` using [`os.devnull`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.devnull) in python 2.7:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as devnull:
...     proc = subprocess.Popen(('ls', 'asdfqwer'),
...                             stdout=devnull,
...                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
...     proc.communicate()
...     proc.returncode
... 
(None, "ls: cannot access 'asdfqwer': No such file or directory\n")
2
```

Communicate sends input to stdin, if piped, and reads from stdout and stderr until end-of-file is reached.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a simple way to do it.